# How to activate ABAP editor code completion

Tags: abap, code-completion

I have the keyword code completion, but not the variable name, table fields, class methods one.

I want those things too, and i heard it's possible. Does that require some additional tool, or is it a matter of configuration?

Thx, you guys rule!

P.S. version 7.10 for the gui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matter of the version. For most of the versions out there, only a basic support for code completion is possible because the editor can't "call back" to the server to get the structural information required for the really intelligent stuff. You can try to activate the option ["Suggest non-keywords from the text"](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_tm80/helpdata/en/43/2ab10bb7380b1ae10000000a1553f6/frameset.htm) - YMMV. For the [really cool stuff](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nwpi71/helpdata/en/45/42cd853e4b5b3de10000000a1553f6/frameset.htm), you need NetWeaver 2007 and up.